# Como fazer autorização com middleware - gin gonic go

Tags: golang

Quero que meu Test function seja exibido no postman apenas se tiver os requisitos do meu func TokenAuthMiddleware.

Mas independente do meu body (no postman) estar preenchido ou não, minha função Teste está sendo chamada (com ou sem autenticação) como resolver isso? eu quero que minha função de teste seja exibida somente depois de passar pelo middleware

Eu tentei algo assim:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func TokenAuthMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Erro ao ler variaveis de ambiente")
    }
    requiredToken := os.Getenv("API_TOKEN")

    if requiredToken == "" {
        log.Fatal("Por favor, defina a variavel API_TOKEN")
    }

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        token := c.Request.FormValue("api_token")

        if token == "" {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Token deve ser preenchido"})

        } else if token != requiredToken {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Token invalido"})

        }
        c.Next()
    }

}

func Teste(c *gin.Context) {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "sucess": "so beautiful",
    })
}

func main() {

    api := gin.New()

    v1 := api.Group("v1")
    v1.Use(TokenAuthMiddleware())
    v1.GET("/", Teste)

    api.Run()
}
```

Comment: eu editei a sua pergunta para ser mais direta. Caso queira fazer alguma mudança é possível [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/574251/edit). [Saiba os motivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) principalmente a parte que trata de `Não use assinatura, taglines nem cumprimentos.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato o que está ocorrendo com o seu programa é que ele está "retornando as duas respostas". Tanto que quando tentamos executar da maneira que forneceu a implementação é possível ver um aviso (*warning*):

> [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override
> status code 400 with 200

E no momento da execução via algum utilitário de requisições podemos ver as duas respostas no console:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/v1/


{"message":"Token deve ser preenchido"}{"sucess":"so beautiful"}
```

---

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é utilizar a função [`Abort`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Abort).

Segue um exemplo da correção que deve ser feita em seu código:

```
func TokenAuthMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    err := godotenv.Load(".env")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Erro ao ler variaveis de ambiente")
    }
    requiredToken := os.Getenv("API_TOKEN")

    if requiredToken == "" {
        log.Fatal("Por favor, defina a variavel API_TOKEN")
    }

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        token := c.Request.FormValue("api_token")

        if token == "" {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Token deve ser preenchido"})
            c.Abort()
            return

        } else if token != requiredToken {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": "Token invalido"})
            c.Abort()
            return

        }
        c.Next()
    }

}
```

Comment: perfeito perfeito